# Автообновление мини-чата

Tags: ajax

Пишу что-то вроде мини-чата. Как сделать, чтобы блок с сообщения каждую секунду обновлялся, вытягивая из базы сообщения?

Answer (score 4):

```
function updateChat()
    {
        $.getJSON('ajaxURL', {}, function (data)
            {
                //тут пишем код для добавления сообщения визуально в чат
            });
        setTimeout(updateChat, 1000);
    }

updateChat(); // запуск
```

Только лучше сделать интервал побольше: 1 секунда - слишком часто, ИМХО, для мини-чата.
`ajaxurl` - адрес к странице, которая отдаёт новые сообщения в формате `JSON`.

Comment: Это ужас для чата, с большим количеством юзверов
Юзай COMET

Comment: если брать подобные сервисы, я бы посоветовал [Pusher](http://pusher.com/)

Comment: @markuper, на живом примере нормально такой чат работает, так что не надо вот. Сколько вы подразумеваете под большим количеством юзеров? Так-то автор сказал "мини-чат".  
Не могу полностью компетентно спорить, т.к. не разбираюсь в описанной вами технологии, сейчас почитаю.

Comment: Была у нас мотыга, изобрели трактор.

Зачем мы будем юзать трактор, когда есть мотыга. Тем более мы не знаем что он есть, хотя нам и рассказали что он есть.

Comment: @markuper, я понял из форумов, что он непредсказуемо может даже на 300 юзеров загрузить проц на 100% и вовсе не давать обещанной производительности. Это уже пофиксили, не знаете? Т.к. сама по себе штука привлекательная.

Answer (score 2):

Можно использовать `Ajax` c `long polling`, чтобы не бомбить сервер запросами каждую секунду.

Comment: ИМХО, `long polling` в большенсте случаев неоправдано усложняет серверную логику

Comment: не спорю... но 
"чат - средство обмена сообщениями по компьютерной сети в режиме реального времени".

А пример(Construct-а) можно применить, например, для различных уведомлений но не для чата... ИМХО

Comment: @oneboy, да вы что? Куча чатов в онлайн-проектах, типа браузерных игр, использует это и всем хорошо. Согласен, в десктопных приложениях используется реалтайм, но для веба мой способ очень распространённый.  
НО, если там у автора реально надо с частотой секунды проверять (то есть он не придумал это с потолка, а на самом деле можно взять и 5 сек), то тогда да, обычный AJAX каждую секунду ото всех - это плохо.

Comment: @Spectre - зависит от языка и используемой библиотеки, фреймворка.

Comment: безусловно, но я не слышал о фреймворке, с которым `push-приложение` будет _проще_, чем обычное

Comment: Да, но вы не коснулись вопросов нагрузки на сервере и взаимодействия *между пользователями*. Ну да не суть, в целом, наверное, согласен.

Answer (score 2):

И все почему-то забыли про HTML 5 и [WebSocket](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket#_).

Comment: не забыли... дело в кроссбраузерности...